# showContent is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, rollup, rollupjs

Uncaught ReferenceError: showContent is not defined. Although all other modules (main,about) defined. For assembly I use rollup. Where is the mistake?

```
import showContent from 'modules/showContent';
import main from 'modules/screens/main';
import about from 'modules/screens/about';
import blog from 'modules/screens/blog';
import contacts from 'modules/screens/contacts';
import gallery from 'modules/screens/gallery';

$(document).ready(function() {
  showContent(main);
    $(document).on("click", "a", (e) => {
        if ( $(this).hasClass('active') ) return;

        $("a").removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');

        $(".slide").slideUp(800);

        const self = this;
        setTimeout(() => showContent($(self).attr('id')), 800);
    });
});
```

showContent.js

```
const showContent = (contentTemplate) => {
  const content = document.querySelector(`main`);
  content.innerHTML = ``;
  content.appendChild(contentTemplate);
};

export default showContent;
```

rollup.config.js

```
export default {
  entry: 'script.js',
  dest: 'script.min.js',
  format: 'iife',
  sourceMap: 'inline',
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "fsdf",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "script.min.js",
  "devDependencies": {
    "rollup": "^0.50.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

I start assemply using "./node_modules/.bin/rollup -c".
Console: [log1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40iYn.png)
[log2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eF83v.png)